# A formula for the $n$th term of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find a formula for the $n$th term of the sequence
>   $$1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,\ldots.$$

Let $x_n$ denote the $n$th term of the sequence. If
$$1+2+\cdots+m < n \leq 1+2+\cdots+m+(m+1)$$
then $x_n = m+1$. Is this a formula or not?

Comment: It seems that $$\frac1{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{2^n} $$ should be a generating function, but I don't know how to find a closed form...

Comment: @Math1000 OEIS says the generating function is $\frac x{1-x}\prod_{k>0}\frac{1-x^{2k}}{1-x^{2k-1}}$.

Comment: Technically this is not a duplicate, since the answer to the question that you actually asked is that it is not a formula. However, what you have is a start on the way to finding a formula, and the accepted answer at the earlier question gives a very complete discussion of how to continue it.

Comment: @Math1000 - F(z) := (z + z^2 + z^4 + z^8 + z^16 + z^32 + z^64)/(1-z);
taylor(F(z),z,0,50);


$$6\,z^{50}+6\,z^{49}+6\,z^{48}+6\,z^{47}+6\,z^{46}+6\,z^{45}+6\,z^{
 44}+6\,z^{43}+6\,z^{42}+6\,z^{41}+6\,z^{40}+6\,z^{39}+6\,z^{38}+6\,z
 ^{37}+6\,z^{36}+6\,z^{35}+6\,z^{34}+6\,z^{33}+6\,z^{32}+5\,z^{31}+5
 \,z^{30}+5\,z^{29}+5\,z^{28}+5\,z^{27}+5\,z^{26}+5\,z^{25}+5\,z^{24}
 +5\,z^{23}+5\,z^{22}+5\,z^{21}+5\,z^{20}+5\,z^{19}+5\,z^{18}+5\,z^{
 17}+5\,z^{16}+4\,z^{15}+4\,z^{14}+4\,z^{13}+4\,z^{12}+4\,z^{11}+4\,z
 ^{10}+4\,z^9+4\,z^8+3\,z^7+3\,z^6+3\,z^5+3\,z^4+2\,z^3+2\,z^2+z
 +\cdots $$

Comment: @arthur Thanks, that was a classic fallacy of counting $1,2,4,8$ and proceeding to think "powers of $2$!"

Answer (score 0):

It should be $\lfloor\sqrt{2n} + \frac{1}{2}\rfloor$, where $n$ is the term number

Comment: Yes, but where did you get this from?

Comment: OEIS A002024 "n appears n times; floor(sqrt(2n) + 1/2)." http://oeis.org/A002024

Answer (score 0):

This is not considered a formula, because it does not give $x_n$ as a function of $n$ but instead gives (sharp) bounds on what $x_n$ is. Instead, note that

- $x_1=1=T_1$ and it is the last $x_n$ equal to 1
- $x_2=3=T_2$ and it is the last $x_n$ equal to 2
- $x_3=6=T_3$ and it is the last $x_n$ equal to 3, etc.

Here $T_n$ is the $n$th triangular number. There is an analogue of the square root – the triangular root – that yields $n$ given $T_n$:
$$n=\frac{\sqrt{8T_n+1}-1}2$$
Therefore a possible formula for $x_n$ is
$$x_n=\left\lceil\frac{\sqrt{8n+1}-1}2\right\rceil$$
Alternatively, this sequence is [A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024) in the OEIS and a simpler formula given there is
$$x_n=\left\lfloor\sqrt{2n}+\frac12\right\rfloor$$